# Discrimination value for parent class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

If I have the following Maps:

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    this.Id(x => x.Id);
    this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Discriminator");        
}

public class ChildMap : SubClassMap<Child> // Child : Parent
{
    this.DiscriminatorValue("Foo");
}
```

When being created into the database, a `Child` has the Discriminator column value `"Foo"` but when a `Parent` is created it has the value `"MyNamespace.Namespace.Parent"`.

Is there a way I can set a `DicriminatorValue` for `Parent` (e.g. `"Bar"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this [`public class ClassMap<T>`](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/b8aa3ea394504af2ed7f00ef287699ca07410f82/src/FluentNHibernate/Mapping/ClassMap.cs):

The first overload

```
public DiscriminatorPart DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<TDiscriminator>(
    string columnName)
```

The second overload

```
/// <summary>
/// Specify that this entity should use a discriminator with it's subclasses.
/// This is a mapping strategy called table-per-inheritance-hierarchy; where all
/// subclasses are stored in the same table, differenciated by a discriminator
/// column value.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TDiscriminator">Type of the discriminator column</typeparam>
/// <param name="columnName">Discriminator column name</param>
/// <param name="baseClassDiscriminator">Default discriminator value</param>
public DiscriminatorPart DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<TDiscriminator>(
    string columnName, TDiscriminator baseClassDiscriminator)
```

Other words, use the second overload and provide the default value...

Comment: Clearly my brain is a little fuzzy from the SO party last night. Thanks!

Comment: Great if that helped ;) Enjoy NHibernate, great tool

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    this.Id(x => x.Id);
    this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Discriminator", "Bar");        
}

public class ChildMap : SubClassMap<Child> // Child : Parent
{
    this.DiscriminatorValue("Foo");
}
```

The second parameter from the method DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn is the baseClassDescriminator.

Comment: Wow, an answer from 2014 still valid today, thanks a lot :D